# Is this sentence valid considering the phrase after the comma is in stark contrast to what came before it?

Tags: commas

Here's the sentence:

I used to hate planning and I still do, but once I'm done planning, everything's easier.

If I remove the phrase after the first comma, the sentence doesn't make any sense; however, since the last bit is in stark contrast to the first, wouldn't it still be considered grammatically 'correct'?

Comment: By "remove the phrase after the first comma", do you mean the words between the two commas?  Ie, the new sentence would be "I used to hate planning and I still do, everything's easier"?

Comment: Yes, that would be the new sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second half of your sentence does offer a different point of view from the first but that's why you have a contrasting conjunction ("***but***") instead of a joining one (such as "***and***").

Note also that grammar doesn't necessarily cover the logical coherency of a sentence.  This sentence makes no sense by itself but is grammatically correct:

> *I hate avocados so I eat them everyday.*

If you want to split your sentence into two, you can do that:

> *I used to hate planning and I still do.  Once I'm done planning, everything's easier.*

These sentences are both grammatically correct but because they seem to be somewhat at odds with each other, they sound a little off.  You can fix that by adding a word to connect the two while acknowledging the contrast:

> *I used to hate planning and I still do.  Once I'm done planning, **however,** everything's easier.*

or

> *I used to hate planning and I still do.  **However,** once I'm done planning, everything's easier.*

Here the word *however* fills the same role as the word *but* in your original sentence.